# Static class not available in part of my project

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Lets say I got this class:

```
public static class tst
{
   public static string asd
   {
      get;
      set;
   }
}
```

Now, I have ASP.NET MVC project with integrated nuget package of another project (so basically it's 2 projects inside of one). When I set `tst.asd = "fgh";` in ASP.NET MVC part of the project, I can see `"fgh"` in the whole ASP.NET MVC application, but this additional nuget project somehow cannot access it. I mean, I referenced this and all, but it still cannot see the content of the property.

So, my question is, if the `tst` class set by MVC exists in memory, why nuget project cannot access it? Maybe I am doing something wrong? And, the main question - if everything looks good, then how can I scan memory to find address of this class manually?

**Edit**: If I set `asd="something"` property inside of a nuget project, both project are seeing different instances of this static(!) class!

**Edit #2**: I just checked, and ASP.NET MVC runs under different appdomain than this nuget project, and I have read, that static classes are initiated once every appdomain! So how do I change appdomain?

Comment: Does your nuget project have a reference to the namespace of `tst`?

Comment: @BrianM: Yes of course. On the code-side I can easily access that class, no compiler errors are being thrown.

Comment: Try redoing the reference but make sure that you make it a project reference by choosing the project and not the dll file.

Comment: The nuget package probably doesn't have the same app domain as the MVC project. So the nuget package would be looking at a different instance of `tst` than what the MVC side is.

Comment: @BrianM: Yeah, that's it, I just added an edit to my post. Now I need to somehow resolve this.

Comment: Looks like the most common (best?) approach is to utilize [MarshalByRefObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.marshalbyrefobject.aspx) to get the same value across AppDomains.